# Livebindings delphi berlin - Travando

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, firemonkey, delphi-berlin

Migrei meu aplicativo em `firemonkey` que estava rodando no `Delphi-xe8` para o `Delphi Berlin`, tudo funciona perfeitamente, só que quando visualizo o `Bindings designer` e seleciono alguma `query` ou `listview` o projeto trava, simplesmente não consigo fazer nada.
No `Delphi-xe8` estava funcionando normalmente. Alguém já teve esse mesmo problema?

Comment: Você criou um projeto do zero para ver se da o mesmo problema?

Comment: Sim... funciona normalmente